# Having trouble creating an extension type with global C struct variable

Tags: python, cython

I am trying to create a cython wrapper around a C project.  I have been successful at creating some function calls (with help from @DavidW but now I want to wrap much of the API in a single class.  The book I have and other googling says to create an "Extension Type".

Here is code from my .pyx file that works but leaves me with only one function (i.e. en_epanet()) I can call from a python script:

```
cdef extern from "types.h":
    cdef struct Project:  # structure from C project
        pass

ctypedef Project *EN_Project

cdef extern from "epanet2_2.h":
    int EN_createproject(EN_Project *)
    int EN_runproject(EN_Project, const char *, const char *, const char *)
    int EN_deleteproject(EN_Project)
    int EN_open(EN_Project, const char *, const char *, const char *)


def en_epanet(char *f1, char *f2, char *f3):
    cdef:
        EN_Project p
        int errcode
    EN_createproject(&p)
    errcode = EN_runproject(p, f1, f2, f3)
    EN_deleteproject(p)
    return errcode
```

How do I put this into a python class or a cython extension type so I can add more methods/functions to it?

I have tried:

```
cdef class Epanet22:
    cdef:
        EN_Project project
        int errcode
    def __cinit__(self):
        self.p = <EN_Project>malloc(sizeof(Project))
        if not self.p:
            raise MemoryError("Could not allocate memory for EN_Project")
        EN_createproject(self.p)
```

but I get an error when compiling:

> EN_createproject(self.p)
> ^
>
> src\cyepanet.pyx:100:29: Cannot convert Python object to 'EN_Project *'

I need to be able to use/pass the EN_Project attribute in other methods I want to implement from the C project like the EN_runproject() method.

I revised per @DavidW but got a different error:

```
cdef class Epanet22: 
    cdef: 
        EN_Project project 
        int errcode 
    def __cinit__(self): 
        self.project = <EN_Project>malloc(sizeof(Project)) 
        if not self.project: 
            raise MemoryError("Could not allocate memory for EN_Project") 
        EN_createproject(self.project)
```

but got this error:
src\cyepanet.pyx:100:29: Cannot assign type 'EN_Project' to 'EN_Project *'

Revised:

```
cdef class Epanet22:
    cdef:
        EN_Project *project
        int errcode
    def __cinit__(self):
        self.project = <EN_Project*>malloc(sizeof(Project))
        if not self.project:
            raise MemoryError("Could not allocate memory for EN_Project")
        EN_createproject(self.project)
    def __dealloc__(self):
        EN_deleteproject(self.project)
        free(self.project)
```

However now getting this error when I try to set up the **dealloc**:

> EN_deleteproject(self.project) src\cyepanet.pyx:162:29: Cannot assign
> type 'EN_Project *' to 'EN_Project'

More info on the project.  The original C project is at:

[https://github.com/OpenWaterAnalytics/EPANET](https://github.com/OpenWaterAnalytics/EPANET/blob/dev/include/epanet2_2.h)

And the specific toolkit header file that I am trying to write the Cython API on top of is at:

https://github.com/OpenWaterAnalytics/EPANET/blob/dev/include/epanet2_2.h

And the declaration for EN_deleteproject() is:

```
/**
  @brief Deletes a currently opened EPANET project.
  @param[in,out] ph an EPANET project handle which is returned as NULL.
  @return an error code.

  EN_deleteproject should be called after all network analysis has been completed.
  */

int DLLEXPORT EN_deleteproject(EN_Project ph);
```

Comment: Do you mean `self.project` rather than `self.p`? Anything that Cython doesn't know a static type for (possibly because it doesn't exist, like `p` is assumed to be a Python object that's resolved at runtime)

Comment: I revised to:  
cdef class Epanet22:
    cdef:
        EN_Project project
        int errcode
    def __cinit__(self):
        self.project = <EN_Project>malloc(sizeof(Project))
        if not self.project:
            raise MemoryError("Could not allocate memory for EN_Project")
        EN_createproject(self.project)

But got this error:  
src\cyepanet.pyx:100:29: Cannot assign type 'EN_Project' to 'EN_Project *'

Comment: `self.project = <EN_Projec*t>malloc(sizeof(Project))` (I've added a star in the `<>` cast)

Comment: Got a little further with @DavidW suggestion of pointer notation but now a new error.  As you can tell i'm not that good with pointers and pointer notation. :(

Comment: I suspect (but don't know) that deleteproject takes a pointer so should be declared `int EN_deleteproject(EN_Project*)`

Comment: I added some links to the original C project and a clip of the function declaration.

Comment: In which case you need to dereference the pointer with `EN_deleteproject(self.project[0])`

Comment: I think you should use a `@staticmethod` decorator and define a static method to obtain an instance of your `Epanet22`.